# Java - Trouble reading data from a list of 2D arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, nested-lists

I have created a list of 2D arrays containing randomly generated number values for different locations.

```
public static int Prices[][] = new int[Cities.length][ItemNames.length];
public static List<int[][]> CityPrices = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
public static void NewDay()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<Cities.length; ++i)
    {
        Prices[i] = PriceGenerator.ReturnPricesForCity(i); 
        //This method returns an array of random integers
    }
    CityPrices.add(Prices);
}
```

But then later when I want to retrieve the price history for a specific item for the amount of days passed, it returns the same value for each day

```
int Prices[] = new int[GlobalVariables.CityPrices.size()];
String sTest = "";
for(int i = 0; i < Prices.length; ++i)
{
    Prices[i] = GlobalVariables.CityPrices.get(i)[spinCity.getSelectedItemPosition()][spinItem.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    sTest = sTest + Prices[i] + ",";
}
```

In this case, the values returned by sTest was : 6055,6055,6055,6055,6055, for five consecutive days.
If I would for instance add a day, the values would change to a range of a new number, which in this case was : 7294,7294,7294,7294,7294,7294,

Please show me what I am doing wrong, as I have been trying to figure this one out the past 4 days with no luck.

Comment: the problem may be in the method generating the random values.

Comment: Can you post the code for how you generate the random numbers? It looks like it might have to do with the pseudo-random number generator

Comment: Also, you may be misusing 2D arrays

Comment: Thanks guys I found my answer below, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element in your `CityPrices` list is the same: in each case, you are adding the `Prices` two-dimensional array. Your loop modifies `Prices[i]`, but it doesn't change `Prices`, which is still a reference to the same two-dimensional array right the way through.

I think you're imagining it will pass the contents of the array in its current state, but it doesn't: it passes a *reference* to the array to the `.add()` method, so any subsequent changes to the array will be reflected in the contents of `CityPrices`.

If at the end of your loop you try

```
CityPrices.get(0) == CityPrices.get(1)
```

you'll see it returns `true`.

Comment: Hehe thanks, I thought it might be something like that in the end, but did not want to believe it because I did not know what to do instead. I recently decided screw it and just created lists for every item contained in the 2d array, took me a few hours but at least now everything is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

In the assignment: `Prices[i] = GlobalVariables.CityPrices.get(i)[spinCity.getSelectedItemPosition()][spinItem.getSelectedItemPosition()];` you are basically referencing an `int[][]` at the same index for both dimensions.

On top of that, the `spinCity.getSelectedItemPosition()` invocation might be returning the same index at every iteration of your loop, hence your identical values.

It's hard to assume anything further as you haven't posted the code for `spinCity`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, spincity refers to a spinner created on the interface which is basicaly a dropdownlist for android, and the method returns an integer value for the index of the current selected item, and it should return the same index every time during the loop, as the only thing that I want to be changing should be the array retrieved from the list